# Why not reset the connection to the $. ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jsonp

do check the availability of the server and if it is available, then load the scripts.

**the client side**

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp" ,
        timeout: 1000,
        cache: false,
        url: "http://xxx/include/xxx.php?q=?",

        success: function(msg)
        {

  jQuery.getScript("http://xx.xxx-x.ru/include/xx/js/jquery.min.js").done(function(script, textStatus) {
/*then load scripts using getScript. */
})

 },error: function (xOptions, textStatus,jqxhr) {

        console.log( xOptions.abort());
        }

    })

  })
```

**server**

xxx.php

```
    error_reporting(0);
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);
sleep(2000); // Server is dead / hung etc.
if (isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q']))
{
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo $_GET['q'].'()';
}
```

works in *ajax error (timeout)*, but the browser is still trying to retrieve data from the server (probably will be shipping these *2000 sec*) although *timeout = 1s*

what's the problem? brain has already boiled)

*sorry for my bad english*

Comment: Probably browser has own timeout and TCP/IP protocol has own timeout etc. and you can't change it. maybe ajax timeout is for "how long wait for answer" not for "how long keep browser connection or TPC/IP connection". Does it bother you page/script to work ?

Comment: It doesn't let my page work

Comment: The task: you should download scripts to client’s website in case they upload in a second. The scripts are on the third-party site.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use this:

```
<script src="http://xx.xxx-x.ru/include/xx/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if(window.jQuery) {
       /*then load scripts using getScript. */
    }
</script>
```